# How to fix 'Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined' in nodejs? [Script]

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

I'm setting up a new server, and want to run a nodejs script to discord. But the problem is; it posts errors after the script is started/or running.

I have tried to contact "author" without an answer on GitHub to get it fixed, and I did try tested on other servers I have online, but it says the same error. (incl downgrade of nodejs/npm version.)

The code I did found is from this GitHub page: https://github.com/Triniayo/nodejs-discord-csgoupdate

```
// Requirements
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const Parser = require('rss-parser');
const htmlToText = require('html-to-text');
const log = require('npmlog');

// Load Config
const cfg = require('./config.json');

// Create feeder instance
let rssParser = new Parser({
    // Renaming 'content:encoded' to 'contentHtml' because it won't be useable otherwise
    customFields: {
        item: [
            ['content:encoded', 'contentHtml']
        ]
    },
    // Setting User Agent
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'
    }
});

// Setting variables for the RSS output
let updateTitle;
let updateURL;
let updateContent;
let updateDate;

// Setting last update variable
let lastUpdate;

function getLastUpdate() {
    // Getting date of last update from check-update.txt file
    let dateFromFile = fs.readFileSync('check-update.txt');
    lastUpdate = dateFromFile.toString();
}

// Getting last date from check-update.txt file every 5 seconds
setInterval(getLastUpdate, 5000);

// Create Discord Bot Instance
const bot = new Client();

// Logging into Bot Account
bot.on('ready', () => {
    log.info('discord', `Logged in as ${bot.user.tag} (User ID: ${bot.user.id}) on ${bot.guilds.size} server(s)`);
    bot.user.setActivity('Fetching Updates');

    // Checking every 10 seconds if there's a new update, and if it's been posted already
    setInterval(getUpdate, 10000);
});

function getUpdate() {
    // Get current date and edit format
    let getDate = new Date();
    let date = [
        getDate.getFullYear(),
        ('0' + (getDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        ('0' + getDate.getDate()).slice(-2)
    ].join('-');

    // Fetching updates from CS:GO Blog
    (async () => {
        // Setting RSS Feed URL
        let feed = await rssParser.parseURL('http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/category/updates/feed/');

        // Setting items into variables
        feed.items.forEach(item => {
            if (item.isoDate.includes(`${date}`)) {
                updateTitle = item.title;
                updateURL = item.link;
                updateContent = item.contentHtml;
                updateDate = item.isoDate;
            }
        });

        // Converting from HTML to readable text
        let format = htmlToText.fromString(updateContent, {
            wordwrap: 130
        });

        // Limiting the update to 10 lines
        let updateNotes = format.split('\n', 10);

        if (updateDate.includes(`${date}`)) {
            if (lastUpdate !== date) {
                bot.channels.get(cfg.channelid).send("@everyone A new CS:GO Update has been released!", {
                    embed: {
                      "title": `${updateTitle}`,
                      "description": `${updateNotes.join('\n')}...\n\n[Continue reading on the CS:GO Blog](${updateURL})`,
                      "url": `${updateURL}`,
                      "color": 5478908,
                      "thumbnail": {
                        "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Triniayo/nodejs-discord-csgoupdate/master/csgo-icon.png"
                      }
                    }
                });

                // Storing date of the latest update in the check-update.txt
                fs.writeFileSync('check-update.txt', `${date}`)
            }
        } else {
            // Do nothing if update has been posted already.
        }
    })();
}

// Logging into the Bot Account
bot.login(cfg.token);
```

On below this, is the error, I'm getting after I did updated nodejs & npm to the newest version.

```sh
(node:23692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
    at /home/mikkel/bots/csgo/app.js:87:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:23692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 13)
```

I don't know, what this error does mean since I'm noob to nodejs.

Version, of npm/node:

```sh
node: v8.16.1
npm: 6.12.0
```

What is it that I must have changed. I have no sense of javascript or nodejs. the script lay freely on GitHub.

**Update: edited 10/10/2019 - 15:28**:
What with date format? - Example; on the github, it reading from check-update.txt with this format: 10/23/2018 (e.g)

Seems it doesn't post for me on Discord. (which it should do if it doesn't do it)

Example:

```
    // Checking every 10 seconds if there's a new update, and if it's been posted already
    setInterval(getUpdate, 10000);
```

Here is the problem:

```
            // Do nothing if update has been posted already.
        }
    })();
}
```

Maybe I should create a new bot from discord developers?

Comment: _"Cannot read property `includes` of undefined"_ > `if (item.isoDate.includes(\`${date}\`)) {` There, `item.isoDate` appears to be `undefined`.

Comment: @Cerbrus, I see what you mean. but how can it be the problem? - That's strange for me.

Comment: add extra condition like _updateDate_ is not _null/undefined_ and has _length_
For ex: `if (updateDate && updateDate.length && updateDate.includes(`${date}`))`

Comment: If `isoDate` is undefined, how can it call the `.includes` on that? It can’t.

Comment: **includes** is used on array or strings types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it. request url `http` to `https`, `isoDate` to `pubDate`. isoDate is not in the feed content.

```js
// Setting RSS Feed URL
let feed = await rssParser.parseURL('https://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/category/updates/feed/');

// Setting items into variables
feed.items.forEach(item => {
  if (item.pubDate.includes(`${date}`)) {
    updateTitle = item.title;
    updateURL = item.link;
    updateContent = item.contentHtml;
    updateDate = item.pubDate || '';
  }
});
```

Comment: What with date format? - Example; on the github, it reading from check-update.txt with this format: 10/23/2018 (e.g)

Seems it doesn't post for me on Discord. (which it should do if it doesn't do it)

Example:
```node
    // Checking every 10 seconds if there's a new update, and if it's been posted already
    setInterval(getUpdate, 10000);
```

Here is the problem:
```node
            // Do nothing if update has been posted already.
        }
    })();
}
```

Maybe I should create a new bot from discord developers?

(I have updated my question upper!)

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted reads as follows:

```
(node:23692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
    at /home/mikkel/bots/csgo/app.js:87:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

The first line of the error message is saying is trying to call `includes`, or get the `includes` property of an object, but that the object is undefined.
The second line of the error message is telling you where the problem is occurring; line 87 (and column 24).

Line 87 reads:

```
if (updateDate.includes(`${date}`)) {
```

So the `updateDate` object must be undefined somehow. Looking through, we see that it is only set in the forEach loop on line 70, but that it's in an if statement inside this loop.

```
feed.items.forEach(item => {
    if (item.isoDate.includes(`${date}`)) {
        updateTitle = item.title;
        updateURL = item.link;
        updateContent = item.contentHtml;
        updateDate = item.isoDate;
    }
});
```

If the loop never runs, then `updateDate` will never be set. If every item in the loop doesn't include the date in their `isoDate` property, then `updateDate` will never be set.

So we must guard against these cases.

We can add a condition that `updateDate` has been set to something by changing line 87 to this:

```
if (updateDate && updateDate.includes(`${date}`)) {
```

Comment: Hi @IMP1, thanks for the information.

I have updated it, no more errors. But it should "post" an update on discord. 

because there was an update (today 09-10-19 - depends on the format of date)

So actually, it should post "update" automatic from the RSS >> 
https://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/category/updates/feed/ - Example.

So dunno, about I should update of check-update.txt of date formating:
```bash
2019.10.09
10.09.2019
10/09/2019
09/10/2019
or 09/10/19
```

Comment: Hi @mrc4tt: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Today is the 10th, though. Does that make a difference? What happens if you manually set the values of the day it looks for?
To do this, add a line like this `date = "2019-10-09";` on line 64.